# Unlimited rows with bottom and top shadows

Tags: html, css

I need to implement shadows for the rows. That rows has no margins. So bottom shadow of the row 1 covers the row 2 top part.

I've create a [jsFiddle example of what I need.](http://jsfiddle.net/qh68V/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:10"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:9"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:8"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:7"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:6"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:5"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:4"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:3"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:2"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow" style="z-index:1"></div>
```

CSS

```
.row-with-shadow {
    height:100px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background:#eee;
    box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position:relative;
}
```

It seems that wouldn't work for the rows without bottom and top margins. ? It seems we have to add `z-index` for each row that case.

1 row - z-index 10

2 row - z-idndex 9

...

10 row - z-index 1

But what if we have unlimited rows? Do we need js to do that? 
What if we have 1000rows? it could be that z-index 1000 will cover any UI elements like light boxes.

examle http://jsfiddle.net/qh68V/

HTML

```
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
<div class="row-with-shadow"></div>
```

CSS

```
.row-with-shadow {
    height:100px;
    margin:3px;
    padding:0;    
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background:#eee;
    box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: fix me if am wrong: But I think shadow is also included in the css3 box modell. So you got no overlapping. If you want so, you need to add position: absolute and an increasing z-index for more rows downside.

Comment: It looks fine in Chrome to me: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s78/sh/bd4c53ec-73e3-4c91-b355-ba9df7fb5c42/cc9abff143a4a1d7c60f38fec22b96d3

Comment: The problem is that i searched the way for maki bottom shadow of row 1 lie on the row 2. Not under, as it's on your screenshot.

Comment: I have added some more examples, so you'll understand the problem and solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using a `:after` element and applying the shadow to that..

```
.row-with-shadow {
    height:100px;
    padding:0;    
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background:#eee;
    position:relative;
}
.row-with-shadow:after{
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
   box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   z-index:10;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qh68V/2

Comment: This is absolutely the best way. BTW, I was working on this: http://jsfiddle.net/qh68V/5/ It might be an option.

Comment: Yes, i didn't even thought about this one. But i think my answer is rather better. Next block inside shidow didn't affect position:relative/absolute,z-index, and can't be overrrided by overflow:hidden.

Comment: @HashemQolami, very good.  it is what Rantiev does in his own answer but you have used the right values to eliminate bleeding shadows from left/right/bottom..

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use a gradient background. That will give you better control over the effect.

Adding the following styles seems to work well, although it doesn't handle the first row correctly.

```
border-top:1px solid #808080;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bcbcbc 0%,#eee 6%,#eee 100%);
```

To fix the first row you need the following style:

```
.row-with-shadow:first-child{
    background:#eee;
}
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qh68V/7/

Comment: Good as well. But it affect background, what if we have image that should cover all the block background. But thanks for the answer, anyway. This way can be used as well.

Comment: @Rantiev Not a problem because you can have multiple background images :D